# Running mysql procedure from ant build script

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, ant

I am trying to execute a sql script which creates a procedure and execute it. I have verfier the procedure by running it manually from mysql client. But when is use the below script it gives an error.

my ant script is

```
<sql driver="${mysql.driver.string.DE}" url="jdbc:mysql://${database.host}:${database.port}/${database.name}" userid="${database.username}" password="${database.password}" onerror="continue" delimiter="$$" delimitertype="row" keepformat="yes" rdbms="mysql">
    <transaction src="${mysql.dbupgrade.sql.dir.DE}/fixDuplicateClassNames.sql" />
    <transaction>commit;</transaction>
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir.DE}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</sql>
```

the error thrown on running the script is

```
java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error or access violation message from server: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $;
```

Comment: The error is coming from the fixDuplicateClassNames.sql file - could you attach the contents of that file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know the DELIMITER attribute are not possible in a "file-x.sql" used by ANT. You have to set it in the "sql.. tag"

if you set delimiter="$$" and *NOT delimitertype="row"* in the ANT script this will work. No need to switch back to "delimiter ;"

**file-x.sql**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS Just$$


CREATE FUNCTION Just( xID SMALLINT )
RETURNS CHAR(30)
BEGIN
  DECLARE fun CHAR(30) DEFAULT '' ;
  SELECT name INTO fun FROM family WHERE ID=xID;
  RETURN fun;
END;
$$


insert into idcart (ID,gruppe,sort,beschr1)values(352, 35, 1,'just for fun')$$
insert into idcart (ID,gruppe,sort,beschr1)values(353, 35, 1,'just for fun');
```

Take care to set all $$, you can let the last line by ";" . But if you set the line above not ending with $$ -- then ERROR. If you use delimitertype="row" then all your $$ in the "file-x.sql" will be translated to $ (only one sign) and that throws many errors.